# send textfield text from inside tableView to outside button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, textfield

I have a table with a textfield inside it. I want to send what user types by clicking a button. But the button is not inside the table.

So I used this simple function to pass text from textfield to this variable:

```
extension TableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        amountFromCell = textField.text!
        print(amountFromCell)
        
    }
    
}
```

I ran code and it prints whatever I type in the textfield in the console. But this variable as you can see is defined in `TableViewCell` not where Button is present.
So I created another variable `amountFromCell` in TableViewCell class to store data to it.

And did something like this :

```
amountFromTable = cell.amountFromCell
        
return cell
```

and finally ran this code ..which is when I click button:

```
@IBAction func btnPrintAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(amountFromTable)
}
```

But it returns empty.

So I know I have value in `amountFromcell` but not sure if using `amountFromTable = cell.amountFromCell` while returning cell adds it to `amountFromTable` or not.

Or maybe `amountFromTable = cell.amountFromCell` adds `nil` when cell is created and its not getting latest value from the textField.

Im confused how to send data from this textfield which is inside table to variable defined outside tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Table view cells are not tightly coupled to the table views that contain them. The table view creates cells as needed, then "puts them in the recycle bin" when they scroll off screen, and re-uses them to display new information when a new cell scrolls on screen.

You should set up your code to collect the information from the views in a cell as the user enters it and save it into your data model. (Text input, for example). If you don't collect user input right away, it can be lost if the user scrolls an edited cell off-screen.

There are various ways to pass user input from table view cells back to the view controller so you can store it in your data model.

Here's one:

Create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. Give it an indexPath property so it knows which position in the model it's data belongs in.

Define a `CellDataDidChangeProtocol` with methods like `textDidChange(_:atIndexPath:)` to tell the view controller that the user entered new data for the cell (text field input, switch settings, etc.) Give your cell a delegate property that conforms to that protocol.

In your table view data source's `cellForRow(at:)` method, set the index path of the cell and set its delegate property to point to the view controller. Have the view controller implement your cell delegate protocol.

Have your table view cells detect input in their text fields, and pass the updated data to their delegate.

In your view controller, when the user taps the send button, fetch the data from the model and send it wherever it needs to be sent.